# tunneling socket could not be established

Tags: npm, node-red, tensorflow.js

I am trying to install tensorflow-js in node red via the mannage palette and I get the following error:

```
2021-06-26T11:08:30.367Z Install : node-red-contrib-tf-model 0.1.10

2021-06-26T11:08:30.484Z npm install --no-audit --no-update-notifier --save --save-prefix="~" --production node-red-contrib-tf-model@0.1.10
2021-06-26T11:09:46.719Z [err] npm
2021-06-26T11:09:46.720Z [err] ERR!
2021-06-26T11:09:46.720Z [err]  Linux 4.18.0-15-generic
2021-06-26T11:09:46.720Z [err] npm
2021-06-26T11:09:46.721Z [err] ERR!
2021-06-26T11:09:46.721Z [err] argv
2021-06-26T11:09:46.721Z [err]  "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--no-audit" "--no-update-notifier" "--save" "--save-prefix=\"~\"" "--production" "node-red-contrib-tf-model@0.1.10"
2021-06-26T11:09:46.721Z [err] npm 
2021-06-26T11:09:46.721Z [err] ERR! 
2021-06-26T11:09:46.722Z [err] node
2021-06-26T11:09:46.722Z [err]  v8.10.0
2021-06-26T11:09:46.722Z [err] npm  
2021-06-26T11:09:46.722Z [err] ERR! 
2021-06-26T11:09:46.722Z [err] npm 
2021-06-26T11:09:46.722Z [err]  v3.5.2
2021-06-26T11:09:46.722Z [err] npm
2021-06-26T11:09:46.723Z [err] ERR! 
2021-06-26T11:09:46.723Z [err] code
2021-06-26T11:09:46.723Z [err]  ECONNRESET
2021-06-26T11:09:46.725Z [err] npm 
2021-06-26T11:09:46.725Z [err] ERR! 
2021-06-26T11:09:46.725Z [err] network
2021-06-26T11:09:46.725Z [err]  tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.ru proxy.company.ru:8080
2021-06-26T11:09:46.725Z [err] npm 
2021-06-26T11:09:46.726Z [err] ERR!
2021-06-26T11:09:46.726Z [err] network
2021-06-26T11:09:46.726Z [err]  This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
2021-06-26T11:09:46.726Z [err] npm 
2021-06-26T11:09:46.726Z [err] ERR!
2021-06-26T11:09:46.726Z [err] network
2021-06-26T11:09:46.726Z [err]  and is related to network connectivity.
2021-06-26T11:09:46.726Z [err] npm 
2021-06-26T11:09:46.727Z [err] ERR!
2021-06-26T11:09:46.727Z [err] network
2021-06-26T11:09:46.727Z [err]  In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
2021-06-26T11:09:46.727Z [err] npm 
2021-06-26T11:09:46.727Z [err] ERR!
2021-06-26T11:09:46.727Z [err] network 
2021-06-26T11:09:46.728Z [err] npm
2021-06-26T11:09:46.728Z [err] ERR!
2021-06-26T11:09:46.728Z [err] network
2021-06-26T11:09:46.728Z [err]  If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
2021-06-26T11:09:46.728Z [err] npm
2021-06-26T11:09:46.728Z [err] ERR!  
2021-06-26T11:09:46.728Z [err] network
2021-06-26T11:09:46.729Z [err]  'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
2021-06-26T11:09:46.744Z [err] npm
2021-06-26T11:09:46.744Z [err] ERR!
2021-06-26T11:09:46.744Z [err]  Please include the following file with any support request:
2021-06-26T11:09:46.744Z [err] npm
2021-06-26T11:09:46.744Z [err] ERR!
2021-06-26T11:09:46.745Z [err]      /root/.node-red/npm-debug.log
2021-06-26T11:09:46.751Z rc=1
```

As far as I understand, the problem is in the proxy. Tried  `npm config delete prox` y and `npm config set strict-ssl=false` but the result is the same.
Also tried `npm config rm proxy` and
`npm config rm https-proxy` which also did not succeed.
Can you advise on how to solve this problem?

Comment: `ENOTFOUND proxy.company.ru` implies that your machine can not resolve the hostname `proxy.company.ru` Also are you sure you get exactly the same error after disabling the npm proxy settings?

Comment: As I said, I tried what is written above, the result is the same

Comment: Edit the question to include information about what OS you are running on and what environment variables are set e.g. `HTTP_PROXY`?

Comment: Also can you use tools like nslookup to resolve the proxy's hostname?